# Is it possible to query the avg time in ms per read/write

Tags: sql-server-2012, san

I was wondering if it was possible to obtain the avg block read and avg block write in ms with a query in SQL Server.

If SQL Server knows how many IO requests are made for a given wait type and how long it took to obtain in total, then we should be able to identify how long it takes per request.
I'm assuming that a request would be a block read.

Can we obtain that information with TSQL?